run docker container with timer (delay)
I'm running 20 container in my docker, i have some issue if all run at same time, after 5 containers run the rest will be show too many request in each the logs.
how to setup delay 1 minute or more from one container to next container, so next container will run 1 minute more after first container success run.
atm i just do by manual reset the rest container by manual
is it possible do this in portainer?
thanks.

How are you starting the containers?  Have you tried things like putting a sleep call in your script, or retrieving docker logs separately for each container as it completes?

You can use docker compose and healthchecks for this purposes:
For example:
version: '3.8'

services:
  service1:
    image: <your_image1>
    container_name: container1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:80"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s

  service2:
    image: <your_image2>
    container_name: container2
    depends_on:
      service1:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: sh -c "sleep 60"

  service3:
    image: <your_image3>
    container_name: container3
    depends_on:
      service2:
        condition: service_healthy
    command: sh -c "sleep 60"


What is the issue that you face while running all the containers at same time, In my opinion it would be dependency of one container over the other.
To answer your question you may use the docker compose as below to add delays

version: '3'
services:
  container1:
    image: your-image-1
    command: bash -c "sleep 0 && your-original-command-1"

  container2:
    image: your-image-2
    depends_on:
      - container1
    command: bash -c "sleep 60 && your-original-command-2"

  container3:
    image: your-image-3
    depends_on:
      - container2
    command: bash -c "sleep 60 && your-original-command-3"

  container4:
    image: your-image-4
    depends_on:
      - container3
    command: bash -c "sleep 60 && your-original-command-4"

  container5:
    image: your-image-5
    depends_on:
      - container4
    command: bash -c "sleep 60 && your-original-command-5"

